# How to retain the 0 value after the view page is rendered?

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, timepicker

My Code on View page:

```
Html.LabelFor(x => x.StartTime, new {@class = ""}), Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.StartTime, new
                                     {
                                         @class = "startTime form-time", @Value = Model.StartTime.HasValue
                                                                                                       ? new DateTime(Model.StartTime.Value.Ticks).ToString("h:mm tt")
                                                                                                       : string.Empty
                                     })
```

I have slected **08:00 AM** in TimePicker using Jquery in a Start Time field. But after selecting a value from the dropdown field (going to server side), the timepicker filed value changed to **8:00 AM** after the view page is rendered. That is, it removes the **0** value. But I want the value to be as it is like **08:00 AM**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't "remove" the **0** value - it was *never there* - is this as simple as needing to use `hh:mm tt` instead of `h:mm tt` ?

Comment: Working fine as expected. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define this in your timepicker configuration like

```
$('#timepicker').timepicker({
    showPeriod: true,
    showLeadingZero: true
});
```

You can find more information on Francois Gelinas page on [TimePicker](http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/)

Comment: I included the `showLeadingZero: true` but even though `0` value has been removed.